# How can i handle error with redis and bluebird?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

I've been facing with problem with redis and async await.

I have old redis.get with callback:

```
redis.get(token, async (error, result) => {
            if (error) {
                return res.status(404).json({ msg: 'Confirm token is invalid.' });
            }

            if (result === null) {
                return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Confirm token is expired.' });
            }
})
```

But i will want to refactor him to async/await

```
bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.RedisClient.prototype);
bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.Multi.prototype);
const result = async redis.asyncGet(token)
```

I successfully get the result, BUT how can i get the error ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Having your code, you just need to surround the redis call using async/await syntax in a try/catch statement:

```
bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.RedisClient.prototype);
bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.Multi.prototype);

try {
  const result = redis.get(token);
} catch (e) {
  return res.status(400).send({ msg: 'Confirm token is expired.' })
}
```